# itertools.permutations of Pandas dataframe index uses too much memory

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, python-itertools

I'm trying to make a new Dataframe based on a permutation of another Dataframe.  Here is the original Dataframe.  Price is the index.

```
df1
Price     Bid   Ask
1          .01   .05
2          .04   .08
3          .1    .15  
.           .      .
130        2.50  3.00
```

The second Dataframe is meant to take the index from df1 and create a Dataframe (df2) with permutations of df1 index based on 4 prices such as in the example output below.

```
df2
 #     price1   price2   price 3  price 4
 1       1        2         3       4
 2       1        2         3       5
 3       1        2         3       6
 ..       ..       ..        ..      ..
```

To achieve this, I've been using `itertools.permutation`, but I'm having memory issues and cannot execute the huge number of permutations.  This is the code I've been using to make the permutations.

```
price_combos = list(x for x in itertools.permutations(df1.index, 4))
df2 = pd.DataFrame(price_combos , columns=('price1', 'price2', 'price3', 'price4'))
```

Comment: How many rows does the initial dataframe have?

Comment: Presumably 130, giving around 212m rows. At that scale Pandas is really straining, even if you use memory-optimisation techniques like explicit dtypes. Numpy might work for pure matrix math. Or Big Data tools like Spark, depending on your needs.

Comment: 127 rows of data in the initial dataframe

Comment: Two possibilities: 1) write price_combos to a file.  Then when you load the file using `df = pd.read_csv` with a chunksize, DataFrame df will be an iterator and not have to fit into memory at once.  More info: [Efficient Pandas: Using Chunksize for Large Data Sets](https://medium.com/towards-artificial-intelligence/efficient-pandas-using-chunksize-for-large-data-sets-c66bf3037f93), 2) other option is use of Python [Dask DataFrames](https://dask.org/) which partitions large datasets into the equivalent of smaller DataFrames, so that the smaller ones fit into memory.

Comment: I would try to make sure you really need all these permutations `127 * 126 * 125 * 124 = 248 031 000` is a lot. Do you need to have them all available at the same time? Try to rethink the problem before you start doing fancy things...

Comment: I will try to filter it down but don't think I can get it down that much

Answer (score 1):

- `dtypes` are probably causing the memory allocation to balloon.

  - The `df1.index` is `Int64Index`
  - The best thing I found, for your scenario, is to set the dataframe index into a numpy array with an `int16` dtype.

    - The numeric range of `int8` is -128 to 128.  Since your index is 0 to 130, `int8` will not suffice.
  - Creating a `price_combos` variable and then a dataframe, will use twice the amount of memory, so create `df2` without the intermediary step.
  - If you create the dataframe without specifying the `dtype`, as you're doing, the `dtype` will be `int64`
  - With the following implementation, there will be one object, `df2`, that will be 2,180,905,112 Bytes

    - With the original implementation, there would be two `int64` objects of 8GB each, for a total of 16GB.
- If you're using Jupyter, it has terrible memory management.
- Perhaps increasing the the amount of virtual memory / swap file size, will give you the extra buffer needed memory. Virtual memory is Windows, swap file is Linux. It's easy to do, just Google it.

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas a pd
from itertools import permutations

# synthetic data set and create dataframe
np.random.seed(365)
data = {'Price': list(range(1, 131)),
        'Bid': [np.random.randint(1, 10)*0.1 for _ in range(130)]}

df1 = pd.DataFrame(data)
df1['Ask'] = df1.Bid + 0.15
df1.set_index('Price', inplace=True)

# convert the index to an int16 array
values = df1.index.to_numpy(dtype='int16')

# create df2
%%time
df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.array(list(permutations(values, 4))), columns=('price1', 'price2', 'price3', 'price4')) 
>>> Wall time: 2min 45s

print(df2.info())
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 272613120 entries, 0 to 272613119
Data columns (total 4 columns):
 #   Column  Dtype
---  ------  -----
 0   price1  int16
 1   price2  int16
 2   price3  int16
 3   price4  int16
dtypes: int16(4)
memory usage: 2.0 GB
```

#### `df2.head()`

```py
   price1  price2  price3  price4
0       1       2       3       4
1       1       2       3       5
2       1       2       3       6
3       1       2       3       7
4       1       2       3       8
```

#### `df2.tail()`

```py
           price1  price2  price3  price4
272613115     130     129     128     123
272613116     130     129     128     124
272613117     130     129     128     125
272613118     130     129     128     126
272613119     130     129     128     127
```